# Is it possible to cast a method?

Tags: java, polymorphism

Good evening,

i just asked myself, if it is possible to cast a method.

```
public class A{ 
  public void A_method() {
    System.out.println("THIS is A Class --> A_method");
  }
}

 public class B extends A{

  @Override
  public void A_method() {
    System.out.println("THIS is B Class --> A_method");
  }
}

    public class Main {
       public static void main(String[] args){
       A a = new A();
       a.A_method();
    }
}
```

Output: "THIS is A Class --> A_method".

I tried to cast it like this:

```
((B)a.A_method());
```

It should print: THIS is B Class --> A_method

but it is not working.
Is it possible to cast methods like this?

Thanks

Comment: You're looking to cast a superclass to a subclass, I think, not methods.

Comment: No it is not possible to "cast" methods... the syntax you have provided `((B)a.A_method());` is attempting to cast the result of `A_method()` (which is void) to a class`B` reference.. You might need to look more into the difference between references and objects in Java

Answer (score 2):

It’s not possible to cast methods, casting only works on types (objects and primitives).

If you want to invoke the method overriden in the subclass `B`, then you need to have the object on which the method is called be of type `B`:

```
A a = new B();  // the declaration type can be A but the object is a B
```

or

```
B b = new B();
```

There is no other way: as long as the runtime type is not `B`, it will never call the method overriden in `B`. That’s simply how polymorphism works.